# Microsoft Designer Bluetooth Keyboard - Bluman-manager

Tags: shell-script, keyboard, bluetooth

I am running a Debian 8 Xfce desktop. Just got the *Microsoft Designer Bluetooth Keyboard and Mouse*. 
Using `blueman-manager` I can search for and then pair both the keyboard and mouse. Although, If left idle the connection is lost, and I must then plug in an old mouse and re-pair the new device's through the `blueman-manager` GUI.

I also want my system to pick up/pair the keyboard & mouse on start up, *Currently it does not.*

I'm imagining a script could be written and resolve this issue ?

All help greatly appreciated, **Cheers**.

Comment: are you able to connect and use your Microsoft Designer Mouse? I've Debian Stretch (9), I can pair and connect with the mouse, but the pointer does not move.

Comment: I have previously been able to connect both the mouse and keyboard, but the system would time out, so to speak, and I would have to reconnect them .. The issue being re-pairing them would not work 9/10 and now it seems the initial connection wont work either.

Comment: Meanwhile I tried to pair and connect the mouse on a live cd with Ubuntu desktop gnome 16.10 and using bluetoothctl I made it easily (and I have no timeout/disconnection problems). I wonder what are the key differences concerning bluetooth on Debian 9 and Ubuntu 16.10 (kernel flags? Modules? Command versions? Firmwares?)

Comment: Well that's good news for you FSp, that is if you wish to drive Ubuntu on the daily ? Do post back here if you find out any answers to the questions you wonder about re; kernel flags etc. I'm thinking I will have a dedicated Windows Machine at some point and just use the Keyboard/Mouse then haha ! Currently interested in trying a Mechanical keyboard from Ducky.. Good old hard wired solution haha.